# Unable to use a public typed property in php 7.4 Laravel 7

Tags: variables, visibility, declaration, laravel-7, php-7.4

When I deploy my Laravel application on an Apache web server, I get the following error on line 17 (`public int $invite_id;`).

> "syntax error, unexpected 'Int' (T_STRING), expecting function
>   (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST)"

This is the file the error comes from: (UPDATED Int TO int)

```php
namespace App\Events\Invite;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class Created
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public int $invite_id;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @param  int  $invite_id
     */
    public function __construct(int $invite_id)
    {
        $this->invite_id = $invite_id;
    }
}
```

Locally, everything works fine. When I remove the `Int` everything works fine on the deployment as well. Why can't I specify the type of the public variable?

UPDATE
Inside the composer.json:

```
"require": {
        "php": "^7.4",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^1.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
        "laravel/framework": "^7.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.0"
    },
```

The output of php -v:

> PHP 7.4.4 (cli) (built: Mar 20 2020 13:47:45) ( NTS )
>   Copyright (c) The PHP Group Zend Engine v3.4.0,
>   Copyright (c) Zend Technologies with Zend OPcache v7.4.4,
>   Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies

Comment: `Int` is supposed to be lower cased: `int`. And you're sure your server is running php 7.4?

Comment: when I use ```int``` i get this error: ```syntax error, unexpected 'int' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST)```
The output of php -v: ```PHP 7.4.4 (cli) (built: Mar 20 2020 13:47:45) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.4, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies```

Comment: Most likely the PHP version used by Apache is not the same one you use on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Apache used the php7.2 module indeed.

I changed it by:

```
sudo a2dismod php7.2 && sudo a2enmod php7.4
```

Thanks!